# Reusing InstallShield prerequisites

Tags: installshield, setup-deployment, bootstrapper, prerequisites, installshield-2009

I'm looking to have a release layout with multiple installers but with a single source for prerequisites, in the following structure:

```
\Product1\setup.exe
\Product2\setup.exe
\Product3\setup.exe
\Redist
```

The goal is to launch each prerequisite from the master location instead of duplicating each prerequisite to the its product folder. Is there a way to change the default location of InstallShield's prerequisites (ISSetupPrerequisites)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, that's certainly a useful scenario  I don't think InstallShield handles right now, but I can see two alternatives. First, setting the prerequisites to download their payload it should only need to download once, as once the prerequisite has been installed, each subsequent check should pass.

The second is if your CD/DVD creation program gives enough control, it should be possible to reuse the same file data for multiple locations on the disc. Thus, even though the files are listed multiple times, they don't take up extra room on the media.

Comment: It would be nice if the prerequisite download url can point to a local file on the CD layout, since we can't assume that net access is always available. CD layout creation program is on the roadmap, but not soon enough.